# preloading site images in ajax site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a portfolio web app that is run on Sinatra using `pjax`. If you click 'WORK' and go into each project, you'll see the images load. I want the images to load in the background right when you visit [masedesign.com](http://masedesign.com).

Loading the entire site (approx. 25MB) will cost alot in terms of bandwidth. Perhaps I should load on the first images for each project.

How should I be preloading images in the `img` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var images = ['my.jpg', 'cool.jpg', 'images.jpg'];

$.each(images, function(key, value) { 
    (new Image()).src = value;
});
```

it is using jQuery though, write less do more...

Comment: Write less [sometimes] and load more :P

Comment: Touché. I'm just a pessimist.

Comment: jQuery lib will load while you blink once... what makes websites slow is bad code, and even worse jQuery plugins, and loading same thing 5 times. I tend to write things myself even though they already exist, otherwise you will never learn. jQuery is really helpful, but it is abused by bad coders, just like PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Images start loading when they're placed on the page, or if created in javascript, once you give it a src attribute.

```
image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {

    alert("I loaded!");
}

image.src = imageURL;
```

Comment: Also, if images have a display attribute of none, or if they are in an element with such an attribute, they will not load.